# Property 'files' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I have the following code:

Vue.js

```
   function dropHandler(event: DragEvent) {
    const { files } = event.dataTransfer as HTMLDivElement;
    console.log(files);
   }
```

HTML

```
div.text-center(
    @dragenter.stop.prevent=""
    @dragover.stop.prevent=""
    @drop.stop.prevent="dropHandler"
    @click="$refs.input.click()"
)
```

Even I add `event: DragEvent` and `as HTMLDivElement`, I still have an error: 'Property 'files' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement''.

I understand this error and why this is happening, but I can't find a workaround to do this with typescript, any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you just use `const files = event.dataTransfer.files`! or even const { files } = event.dataTransfer`

Comment: `event.dataTransfer` has type `DataTransfer` not `HTMLDivElement` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent/dataTransfer

Comment: @phuzi my huge mistake! thank you!

Comment: I don't think you need to use `as` to manually cast a type: in fact, see it as an emergency escape hatch (like `!important` is to CSS). By defining event to be `DragEvent` TypeScript should be able to infer the type of `event.dataTransfer.files` directly without any further hints: https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.datatransfer.html